# Access Contact of related Community User

Tags: apex, visualforce

Inside of the community cloud portal I'm creating, I know that I have access to the `{!$User}` object. I'm looking to access fields of the `Contact` object that the `User` object originated from. (By proccess of going to a contact and clicking on *Manage External User* > *Enable Community User*)

I looked up some tutorials and read and came up with this:

```
public class ContactFromUserController {
    private final Contact contact;

    public ContactFromUserController() {
        contact = [
            Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Birthdate
            From Contact
            Where Id In (Select ContactId From User Where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId())
        ];
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
}
```

Anytime I call `{!$contact.FirstName}` in the Visualforce page though, I'm always presented with an error in the IDE:

[image: Force.com IDE Error name does not exist]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access it on the VF page you do not use the `$` as that is a global merge variable. Simply use `{!contact.FirstName}`

You could also simplify your controller a bit by combining the contact properties

```
public Contact contact {get; private set;}
```